# Why doesn't my webpage load the ctx.drawImage()?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, ctx

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <script>
        const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        let background = new Image();
        background.src='background.png';
        ctx.drawImage(background); 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code of the webpage. The path to the image is correct, I checked probably a 100 times. When I continue the code with the main loop it gives me a lot of errors.

I want to make a little 2d game with js, but for some reason the image doesn't load.